# multivariate piecewise-linear equality constraint in optimization problem

Tags: optimization

I have an optimization problem of the type:

$\min f(x) \\
s.t. Ax \le b \\
g(x)=0  $

where $g(x)$ is a piecewise-linear function defined as:

$g(x) = \begin{cases} c_1^Tx & \text{if $x_1+x_2-x_3 \ge 0$} \\ c_2^Tx & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $

I would like to know how to express this problem into a MIP and solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce binaries $\delta_1$and $\delta_2$ satisfying $\delta_1+\delta_2=1$. Now you have two cases, $\delta_1=1$, $c_1^Tx=0$, $x_1+x_2-x_3\geq 0$ and $\delta_2=1$, $c_2^Tx=0$, $x_1+x_2-x_3\leq -\epsilon$. Standard big-M modelling and you have something like

$$ -M(1-\delta_1) \leq c_1^Tx \leq M(1-\delta_1)\\
-M(1-\delta_2) \leq c_2^Tx \leq M(1-\delta_2)\\
x_1+x_2-x_3 \geq -M(1-\delta_1)\\
x_1+x_2-x_3 \leq -\epsilon + M(1-\delta_2)
$$

Of course, in practice you use different big-M constants on each constraint and try to make them as small as possible.

$\delta_1+\delta_2 =1$ is redundant as the two sets are disjoint, but it never hurts to add simple constraints on binaries.

Comment: Since I only have two cases, would it be correct to just use one binary variable $\delta$ and its complement $(1-\delta)$? Or could this cause errors?

Comment: Sure, same thing. Just doesn't generalize as well. Also note that a MILP approach is a pretty large machinery to use if this is the complete model. Simply solve two LPs and you are done.

Comment: Thank you, I cannot solve two LPs because my problem has more than one of these equality constraints (one for each time step). I am aware that it is a pretty heavy computation